# Headless testing Ember application with guard and jasmine

Tags: ember.js, jasmine, phantomjs

I'm trying to use jasmine and guard to test an ember based frontend for my rails 3.2 application. For this, I use jasminerice and guard-jasmine, phantomjs. The setup was very easy and simple and I can run some sample specs. When it comes to play with ember, things go mad. I have the spec below that test a video reader class. It should set videoHeight and  videoWitdh property with the value of the corresponding video DOM element when calling loadVideo method.
When I run jasmine on my browser the test pass, but when I run it with guard and phantomjs, it fails. I got "Expect undefined to equal 640". It seems that my DOM element is not taking into account when the test run on phantomjs.

```
describe "VideoReader", ->
  it "loads video from video DOM element", ->
    videoDOM = Ember.$("<video width='640' height='480'><source src='/test.mp4'></source></video>")[0];

    player = Topper.VideoReader.create();

    player.loadVideo(videoDOM);

    videoHeight = player.get('videoHeight');
    videoWidth  = player.get('videoWidth');

    expect(videoHeight).toEqual(480);
    expect(videoWidth).toEqual(640);
```

Is my spec correctly written ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read the blog post about [Testing in Ember.js](http://www.thesoftwaresimpleton.com/blog/2012/04/03/testing-ember-and-the-runloop/).

I don't know what your `Topper.VideoReader` looks like but I guess your problem has to do with manipulating something on the DOM and not giving Ember.js a chance to propagate those changes.  In your tests you should wrap your calls which interact with bindings or are manipulating the DOM in an `Ember.run(function(){...})` call, as seen in the tests, for example [child_views_test.js](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-views/tests/views/view/child_views_test.js#L30-36).

---

A summary from the discussion below:

- If code you want to test interacts with the DOM, wrap it in an `Ember.run` call.
- If you want to test for events which are fired in your code and you don't have control when exactly they are fired, use the asynchronous test features in the testing framework, like QUnit's [asyncTest](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit/asyncTest)

Comment: my loadVideo method looks like :    

loadVideo: function(videoDOM) {

        this.set('videoHeight',videoDOM.height);
        this.set('videoWidth',videoDOM.width);
    },

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your `loadVideo` call into a `Ember.run(function(){ player.loadVideo(videoDOM); });` ?

Comment: I did it and I understand that my problem is due to the fact that the video element fires events after my expectations. So when I evalue my properties, there're not yet been set. How to make my test waiting for specific event before evaluating expectations ?

Comment: What kind of events are we talking here? Bindings?

Comment: @pangratz you can find the class that I'm trying to test here http://jsfiddle.net/jrabary/TerwV/1/ . The event comes from video element as specified in html 5 API. When the video element is appended in the DOM, it begins to load the video data and fires 'loadstart' event. In my Ember class I capture this event and fire another 'loadstart' event but this time using Ember way. When doing some thing like this my test always fails because the event is fired after the expectation

Comment: @jrabary have you tried wrapping it in an `Ember.run(...)` like this http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/kS34u/ ?

Comment: @pangratz yes! This is what I did. I also put some log and I can see that the expectation is evaluated just right after the Ember.run(_) block. But the event fires sometimes later.

Comment: And what about a `Ember.run.sync()` after appending the view, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/wVjtt/ ?

Comment: @pangratz I got something working not with Ember.run.sync but with Ember.run.later, http://jsfiddle.net/jrabary/TerwV/3/ . It does what I want but I don't know if it the correct way to test stuff like this. May be I should fire the event manualy ?

Comment: @jrabary Hmm, I think you should use something like QUnit's asyncTest (or similar) http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit/asyncTest, since it's not in your control when the event is fired.